# RecyclerView + SearchView Android

Tags: android, xamarin, searchview, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view which has cards in it. I am using a SearchView to filter the List I pass to the Adapter. I have done something like so :-

```
   class EmployeeAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter, IFilterable
    {
        private IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, EmployeeModel>> dupes;
        private Activities.EmployeeActivity employeeActivity;
        private List<IGrouping<string, EmployeeModel>> _items;
        private List<EmployeeModel> mList;
        private CustomTextView txtPlace;
        private CustomTextView txtTime;


        public EmployeeAdapter(List<EmployeeModel> mList, Activities.EmployeeActivity employeeActivity)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.mList = mList;
            this.employeeActivity = employeeActivity;
            dupes = mList.GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName).Where(x => x.Skip(1).Any());
            //Filter = new SuggestionFilter(this);
        }



        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return dupes.Count(); }
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            ViewHolder vh = holder as ViewHolder;
            Typeface faceThin = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(employeeActivity.Assets, "Fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
            Typeface faceBold = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(employeeActivity.Assets, "Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

            vh.txtEmployeeName.Text = dupes.ElementAt(position).Key;
            foreach(EmployeeModel x in dupes.ElementAt(position))
             {

                 var layoutChild = new RelativeLayout(employeeActivity);

                 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                 lp.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentLeft);
                 txtPlace = new CustomTextView(employeeActivity);
                 txtPlace.Text = x.Place;
                txtPlace.LayoutParameters = lp;
                layoutChild.AddView(txtPlace);

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
                 lp1.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);
                 txtTime = new CustomTextView(employeeActivity);

                 txtTime.LayoutParameters = lp1;
                 layoutChild.AddView(txtTime);

                 vh.layoutPeopleRow.AddView(layoutChild);

                 vh.layoutVerticalCheckin.RemoveView(vh.layoutPeopleRow);
                 vh.layoutVerticalCheckin.AddView(vh.layoutPeopleRow);

              }


        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.people_card_row, parent, false);

            // Create a ViewHolder to hold view references inside the CardView:
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
            return vh;
        }
        public class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public CustomTextView txtEmployeeName{ get; private set; }
            public ImageView Image { get; private set; }
            public LinearLayout layoutPeopleRow { get; private set; }
            public LinearLayout layoutVerticalCheckin { get; private set; }

            public CustomTextView txtCheckinTime { get; private set; }


            public ViewHolder(View itemView)
                : base(itemView)
            {
                // Locate and cache view references:
                Image = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgEmpPic);
                txtEmployeeName = itemView.FindViewById<CustomTextView>(Resource.Id.txtEmployeeName);
                layoutPeopleRow = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutPeopleRow);
                layoutVerticalCheckin = itemView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutVerticalCheckin);


            }

        }


        public Filter Filter
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public void AnimateTo(List<EmployeeModel> models)
        {
           ApplyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
           ApplyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
           ApplyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
        }

        private void ApplyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<EmployeeModel> newModels)
        {
            for (int toPosition = newModels.Count() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
                EmployeeModel model = newModels.ElementAt(toPosition);
                int fromPosition = mList.IndexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
               MoveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
                }
         }
        }

        private void MoveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition)
        {
             EmployeeModel model = mList.ElementAt(fromPosition);
             mList.Remove(model);
             mList.Add(model);
            this.NotifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
        }

        private void ApplyAndAnimateAdditions(List<EmployeeModel> newModels)
        {
             for (int i = 0, count = newModels.Count(); i < count; i++) {
                 EmployeeModel model = newModels.ElementAt(i);
            if (!mList.Contains(model)) {
                AddItem(i, model);
            }
        }
        }

        private void AddItem(int i, EmployeeModel model)
        {
            mList.Add(model);
            this.NotifyItemInserted(i);
        }

        private void ApplyAndAnimateRemovals(List<EmployeeModel> newModels)
        {
            for (int i = mList.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            EmployeeModel model = mList.ElementAt(i);
            if (!newModels.Contains(model)) {
                RemoveItem(i);
             }
          }
        }

        private EmployeeModel RemoveItem(int i)
        {
            EmployeeModel model = mList.ElementAt(i);
            mList.Remove(model);
            this.NotifyItemRemoved(i);
            return model;
        }
}
```

There are two problems:

1. The Search is working fine, but when I make a search OnBinderViewHolder is triggered and the components in the OnBindViewHolder show up multiple times.
2. The list goes empty when I search once and the next search shows nothing when I clear the SearchView.

This is my Activity

```
void search_QueryTextChange(object sender, Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView.QueryTextChangeEventArgs e)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewText))
            {
                List<EmployeeModel> filteredModelList = filter(mList, "");
            }
            else
            {
                List<EmployeeModel> filteredModelList = filter(mList, e.NewText);
                mAdapter.AnimateTo(filteredModelList);
                mRecyclerView.ScrollToPosition(0);
            }
        }

        private List<EmployeeCheckinModel> filter(List<EmployeeModel> models, String query)
        {
             query = query.ToLower();

         List<EmployeeModel> filteredModelList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
            foreach (EmployeeModel model in models) {
            String text = model.EmployeeName.ToLower();
            if (text.Contains(query)) {
                filteredModelList.Add(model);
            }
        }
        return filteredModelList;
    }
```